# Too many arguments error if statement (Debian - Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, debian

Really need some help/guidance with this and would be much appreciated if someone could help me!

I'm basically trying to create a shell-script which if process name is entered it will kill it, however if it is a root process it won't.

Now the first part of the script works fine and I can kill process but can't get my head round how to do the if statement.

Please see code below

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n 'Please enter process name:'
read process 
pid1=$( ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep $process | awk'{print $2}' )
pid2=$( ps -NU root | grep $process | awk '{print $1} ' )
if { $pid1 -eq $pid2 ];
echo Kill $process
killall -e $process
else
echo "Unable to kill $process as this is a root process."
fi
```

The error I'm getting when I enter a root process is **line 6: [: too many arguments**

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: for such things, http://www.shellcheck.net really helps.

Comment: The error you posted does not correspond to the code in your question.

Comment: Probably `$pid1` and/or `$pid2` contain spaces. Quoting the variables should resolve the *syntax* error, but there'll still be a logical error.

Comment: ...to clarify: `ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep $process | awk '{print $2}'` can very well return more than one PID. Quoting `$pid1` and `$pid2` will make the `[` command *work*, but perhaps not do what it's meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `if { $pid1 -eq $pid2 ];` with `if [[ $pid1 == $pid2 ]]; then`

Comment: Thanks Jahid trying this just now but getting error "4082: syntax error in expression (error token is '4081 4082") any ideas at all?

Comment: @user1780144 Read my comment to the question. Could you add `set -x` to the script?

Comment: try using `==` instead of `-eq` in the if statement.

Comment: If it solves your problem, you should consider accepting it by clicking on the tick left to the answer